# How to use a theme in dynamic styles with Emotion like CSSProp in styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I just moved from `styled-components` to `emotion`.
In styled-components, I use 'CSSProp' to use the theme in dynamic styles like this :

```
import styled, { CSSProp, css } from "styled-components";

type Style = 'default' | 'fill';
const styles: Record<Style, CSSProp<Theme>> = {
  default: css`
    ${({ theme }: { theme : Theme }) => css`
...

...
const SomeComponent = styled.div`

  ${({ styleType }: { styleType : Style }) => css`
    ${styles[styleType]}
  `}
```

However, I couldn't find a way to do this for 'emotion'. Is there a way?
Maybe you have a solution to my stupid way, let me know. :)